# Send email with embedded images through excel

Tags: vba, excel

Emails I send through excel do not display the embedded images on the receivers end. However the embedded images do display on my end. My guess is that the path is associated with my desktop.

How can I get the images to be displayed? Having trouble figuring out a fix. My code is below:

```
Sub EmailDailyFlow()
Dim mainWB As Workbook


Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook


With olMail
    .To = "email@gmail.com"
    .Cc = ""
    .Subject = Format(Date - 1, "M.dd.yyyy") & " " & "MF & VIT Daily Fund Flow"
    .HTMLBody = "<html><body style='font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size: 16px;'>" & _
            "<p>Please see below.</p>" & _
            "<p><u><b>Volatility:</u></b></p>" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\MF.png'>" & _
            "<p><u><b>Muni:</u></b></p>" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\MUNI.png'>" & _
            "<p><u><b>AFC:</u></b></p>" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\AFC.png'>" & _
            "<p><u><b>AFT:</u></b></p>" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\AFT.png'>" & _
            "<p><u><b>VIT:</u></b></p>" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\VIT.png'>" & _
            "<p>Thank you,</p>" & _
            "</body></html>"
.Send

End With
MsgBox ("Daily flow emails sent!")
End Sub`
```

Comment: The local file path is your problem.  You put them on the web and update the src attributes on those image tags.

Comment: Alternatively, create the email as rich text and add the images inline.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Taken from some site long back, but still work like a charm.
Idea is to attach the image in hid­den man­ner and later add it to using image name in the Html­Body.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**Update:**
I've added another function to retrieve image width and height. I've also updated existing sub to incorporate image size.

```
Sub EmailDailyFlow()
    Dim SendID
    Dim CCID
    Dim Subject
    Dim stdPic As StdPicture
    Dim imageSize As String

    Dim strPathImg1 As String
    Dim strFileImg1 As String
    Dim lngWidthImg1 As Long
    Dim lngHeightImg1 As Long

    Dim strPathImg2 As String
    Dim strFileImg2 As String
    Dim lngWidthImg2 As Long
    Dim lngHeightImg2 As Long

    Dim olMail As MailItem  'REQUIRES MICROSOFT OBJECT OUTLOOK LIBRARY REFERENCE

    strPathImg1 = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images"
    strFileImg1 = "MF.png"
    imageSize = GetImageSize(strPathImg1, strFileImg1)
    lngWidthImg1 = CLng(Split(imageSize, ":")(0))
    lngHeightImg1 = CLng(Split(imageSize, ":")(1))

    strPathImg2 = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images"
    strFileImg2 = "MUNI.png"
    imageSize = GetImageSize(strPathImg2, strFileImg2)
    lngWidthImg2 = CLng(Split(imageSize, ":")(0))
    lngHeightImg2 = CLng(Split(imageSize, ":")(1))

    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    SendID = "email@gmail.com"
    CCID = ""
    Subject = Format(Date - 1, "M.dd.yyyy") & " " & "MF & VIT Daily Fund Flow"

    With olMail
        .To = SendID
        If CCID <> "" Then
          .CC = CCID
        End If
        .Subject = Subject
        'ADD THE IMAGE IN HIDDEN MANNER, POSITION AT 0 WILL MAKE IT HIDDEN
        .Attachments.Add strPathImg1 & "\" & strFileImg1, olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add strPathImg2 & "\" & strFileImg2, olByValue, 0

        'NOW ADD IT TO THE HTML BODY USING IMAGE NAME
        'CHANGE THE SRC PROPERTY TO 'cid:your image filename'
        'IT WILL BE CHANGED TO THE CORRECT CID WHEN ITS SENT.
        .HTMLBody = "<html><body style='font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size: 16px;'>" & _
                    "<p>Please see below.</p>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>Volatility:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:" & strFileImg1 & "' width='" & lngWidthImg1 & "' height='" & lngHeightImg1 & "'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>Muni:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:" & strFileImg2 & "' width='" & lngWidthImg2 & "' height='" & lngHeightImg2 & "'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>AFC:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<p>Thank you,</p>" & _
                    "</body></html>"
        '.Display 'UNCOMMENT ME IF YOU WANT TO DISPLAY THE EMAIL
        .Send
    End With

    MsgBox ("Daily flow emails sent!")
End Sub

Function GetImageSize(filePath As String, fileName As String) As String
    'THIS WILL RETURN IMAGE SIZE IN "xyz:xyz" STRING FORMAT
    Dim strImageDimensions As String
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace((filePath))
    Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(fileName)

    strImageDimensions = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
    strImageDimensions = Replace(Mid(strImageDimensions, 2, Len(strImageDimensions) - 2), " x ", ":")
    GetImageSize = strImageDimensions

    Set objFile = Nothing: Set objFolder = Nothing: Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When the email is sent, the attachments are displayed and the embedded images are just frame and not images. Do you know why that's happening? I also had to remove `Dim olMail As MailItem` for it to send the email.

Comment: So i figured out that the display issue, was caused by the image not size not being defined. I added 'width=100% height=100%'. This displays the image, but it is enlarged to fit the 100% width and height. Is there a way to embed the image, and have the image take on its actual size?

Comment: @AndrewRamonMedina, have you tried the updated code...?

Comment: I did try it, I run into an error. I think it has to do with the object reference library. I have them all checked off. DO you know which library I should have to run the script?

Comment: You will only need `Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library` reference for `MailItem` in line `Dim olMail As MailItem`. Pls note you might have different version of that reference as I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Yes I am using Excel 2016. Do you know the 2016 reference?

Comment: Set a reference to `Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library`, where **`xx.x`** represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. If you will open reference window, you will see only one entry for outlook, just use that.

Comment: Sorry for all the back and forth, thank you for your time. I added in the proper reference so `MailItem` works. But The sizing function doesn't work. Do I need to add in another reference or anything else?

Comment: You don't need any more references. I have tested the code and working without any issues. Make sure you are copying/typing exact code. Even single/double quote will make difference.

Comment: I ended up finding a different way to do it, because the images still were not displaying on the recipient's end. But thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`Sub EmailDailyFlow()
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As MailItem
    Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim oAttach1 As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oAttach2 As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oAttach3 As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oAttach4 As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oAttach5 As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach1 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\MF.png")
Set oAttach2 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\Muni.png")
Set oAttach3 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\AFC.png")
Set oAttach4 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\AFT.png")
Set oAttach5 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\MF-VIT Daily Fund Flow\images\VIT.png")
Set olkPA1 = oAttach1.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA2 = oAttach2.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA3 = oAttach3.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA4 = oAttach4.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA5 = oAttach5.PropertyAccessor

olkPA1.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "MF.png"
olkPA2.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "MUNI.png"
olkPA3.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "AFC.png"
olkPA4.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "AFT.png"
olkPA5.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "VIT.png"

oEmail.Close olSave

oEmail.HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size: 16px;'><p>Please see below.</p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:MF.png'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>Muni:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:MUNI.png'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>afcCore:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:AFC.png'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>aft:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:AFT.png'>" & _
                    "<p><u><b>VIT:</u></b></p>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:VIT.png'>" & _
                    "<p>Thank you,</p>" & _

                    "</body>"

oEmail.Save
oEmail.To = "email@email.com"
oEmail.CC = ""
oEmail.Subject = Format(Date - 1, "M.dd.yyyy") & " " & "MF & VIT Daily Fund Flow"
oEmail.Send

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

`End Sub`